# shell script not running the other script inside it

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(</var/www/sym_monitor/man.txt)


if [ "$value" == "true" ]; then

     ps -ef|grep sym |grep -v grep |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;
cd /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin;
sleep 30;

(sudo ./sym --port 8082 --server);

fi
```

I'm trying to run the above script every 10 mins using cron. While running it under root manually the script is doing fine but when I try to run the script inside cron it is executing the (ps -ef|grep sym |grep -v grep |awk '{ print $2 }'|sudo  xargs kill -9;) and it is not executing the script (sudo ./sym --port 8082 --server) and it is not giving any error. Can anybody suggest me any idea?

Comment: Any output from the script? Such is often send by mail or to syslog, depending on your cron configuration. Apart from that: this might be a path issue: you do not set the working directory in your script, so where _is_ `./sym`?

Comment: Nothing no output. Even I'm using echo $PATH just before script(sudo ./sym --port 8082 --server) but it is not printing it (ECHO $PATH;) is this the right command to print path? that script is in (/var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin) location

Comment: Well, first you have to find out where output goes to. So make another small script that outputs some debug string, start it via cron and check your setup where the output might get sent to. This also depends on _which_ crontab you use. Systemwide? root's crontab? A user's crontab? Directing output from cron scripts is well documented, I suggest you start reading the man pages on cron (`man crontab`, `man cron`) if you have problems with this step...

Answer (score 1):

Please check if crontab  is also running in Bash. If not then you might have have to change your shell.

Also when you are running the script manually, ./sym is a location pertaining to your shell. It might not be as per cron. Please use full path to execute ./sym.

Comment: Yes, The cron tab is also running in bash. Yes I tried to use full path still it is not running. So I split it and used (cd /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin) and (sudo ./sym --port 8082 --server). This script is running absolutely fine when executed manually from command line. The problem is it is not running in cron!

Comment: You need to check your cron output. Redirect the error to the file and discard the standard output. use something like this

` * * * * * /path/to/my_job.sh 1> /dev/null 2> /some/other/path/to/my_job.err`

Also as your script is running fine when running manually from Root,check if you are running script in root cron.

Comment: Yes I'm running my script in root cron. I have redirected the output but it seems somehow echo's are not giving any output into file which I re-directed the output to.

Answer (score 0):

sudo may require a password, thus blocking this command.

Removing sudo would solve the problem, I guess.

Comment: sudo doesn't require password when it is running under root. The first command in the above script also consist of sudo but it is executing fine and the second command which consist of sudo is not working.

Comment: Yup I tried. It is not working bcoz it need to run with sudo in command I don't know why? very unfortunate!